# JAVA-8 streams collect advanced usage

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
package streams;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Student{
    String name;
    int age;
    String type;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(String name, int age, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static List<Student> generateData() {

        List<Student> st = Arrays.asList(new Student("Ashish", 27, "College"),
                new Student("Aman", 24, "School"),
                new Student("Rahul", 18, "School"),
                new Student("Ajay", 29, "College"),
                new Student("Mathur", 25, "College"),
                new Student("Modi", 28, "College"),
                new Student("Prem", 15, "School"),
                new Student("Akash", 17, "School"));
        return st;
    }
}
```

---

```
//AdvancedStreamingP2 class uses the Student class

package streams;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class AdvancedStreamingP2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> studentList = Student.generateData();
        System.out.println("\n---------- Extracting Student Name with Max Age by Type -----------");
        Map<String, Optional<Student>> stuMax = studentList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Student::getType, maxBy(comparing(Student::getAge))));
        stuMax.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", Value :" + v.get()));
    }
}
```

I want to extract the student name, with the max age, grouping student by Type. Is it possible by using any combination in "collect" itself?

I want the output like :

```
---------- Extracting Student Name with Max Age by Type -----------

Key : School, Value : Aman
Key : College, Value : Ajay
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I don't want to use this obvious solution :) 
`stuMax.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", Value :" + v.get().getName()));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-). This collector adapts an existing collector to perform an additional finisher operation. In this case, the finisher operation simply returns the name of the Student.

```
Map<String, String> stuMax = 
    studentList.stream()
               .collect(groupingBy(
                    Student::getType, 
                    collectingAndThen(maxBy(comparing(Student::getAge)), v -> v.get().getName()) 
               ));
```

Output:

```
---------- Extracting Student Name with Max Age by Type -----------
Key : School, Value :Aman
Key : College, Value :Ajay
```

Side-note: instead of using `comparing`, you can use [`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) since `Person.getAge()` returns an `int`: this avoids unnecessary boxing.

Comment: great ! , this is the solution I was looking for.  
Also just wanted to crosscheck once, can't we add a mapping condition here somewhere, as a alternate to the use of 'collectingAndThen'

Comment: @Ashu Nope we can't use `mapping` here since this collector will map the Stream element to something and execute a downstream collector on the result of that mapping. But here, we don't need to collect the names of the Student, we need to find the max by age.

Comment: It would be really nice were the `Collector` interface contain the `andThen()` default method: `maxBy(comparing(Student::getAge)).andThen(v -> v.get().getName())`. Dreams, dreams...

Comment: @TagirValeev Especially that `Consumer` and `Function` have `andThen`. It would be weird if one had to write `consumeAndThen`... By the way I found this nice [discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-August/002193.html) about `andThen` on collector. Apparently it wasn't done due to "type inference issues".

Comment: @Tunaki, thanks for the link. I think, now type inference should work better. At least the example in the mailing list should work... Need to check.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki and TagirValeev for the help. I just saw your discussion on `andThen`, was wondering in which case and how, do we use `andThen` with `Consumer` and `Function`

Comment: @Ashu The purpose is composition. [Take a look at this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)

Comment: ok .. thanks
Got a brief usage view of `andThen` in `Functions` in _Java8 in Action_

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout below advanc](https://itexpertsconsultant.wordpress.com/2016/09/19/java-8-consumer-example/)e example of Consumer in java 8:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class Java8ConsumerExample1 {
private static List<Integer> QUERY_RESULTSET_INTEGER = Arrays.asList(new   Integer(1), new Integer(10), new Integer(200), new Integer(101), new Integer(-10), new Integer(0));
private static List<String> QUERY_RESULTSET_STRING = Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F").collect(Collectors.toList());

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // EXAMPLE : 1

    /**
     * Iterator over the Query generated integer list and print on console.
     */
    StubsUtils.forEach(new ExecutorContext() {
        List<Integer> consumerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        /**
         * Let's assume that our query returns set of Integer that would be consume by some caller class or print on console.
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public List<Integer> getQuery() {
            return QUERY_RESULTSET_INTEGER;
        }

        @Override
        public Consumer<Integer> getConsumer() {
            return x -> {
                System.out.println(x);
                consumerList.add(x);
            };
        }
    });

    // EXAMPLE : 2
    /**
     * Iterator over the Query generated String list and print on console.
     */
    StubsUtils.forEach(new ExecutorContext() {
        List<String> consumerList = new ArrayList<String>();

        /**
         * Let's assume that our query returns set of Integer that would be consume by some caller class or print on console.
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public List<String> getQuery() {
            return QUERY_RESULTSET_STRING;
        }

        @Override
        public Consumer<String> getConsumer() {
            return x -> {
                System.out.println(x);
                consumerList.add(x);
            };
        }
    });

}
}
```

StubsUtils.Java

```
 /**
   * Utility class
 */
 class StubsUtils {

 public static void forEach(ExecutorContext executorContext) {
    executorContext.getQuery().forEach(executorContext.getConsumer());
}

}
```

ExecutorContext.Java

```
interface ExecutorContext<E> {

List<Integer> getQuery();

Consumer<E> getConsumer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Consumer example :-

```
    package com;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.function.Consumer;


    public class AdvanceConsumerTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            TestLookupService testLookupService = new TestLookupService();
            testLookupService.forEach("A",val->{
                System.out.println(" Count of 'A' is "+ val);
            });
            System.out.println("******************************************");
            testLookupService.forEach("B",val->{
                System.out.println(" Count of 'B' is "+ val);
            });
            System.out.println("******************************************");
            testLookupService.forEach("C",val->{
                System.out.println(" Count of 'C' is "+ val);
            });

        }
    }

    class TestLookupService {
        void forEach(String parameter, Consumer<Long> stringConsumer) {
            LocalRepository.forEach(new QueryExecutionContext() {
                @Override
                public String getQuery() {
                    return parameter;
                }

                @Override
                public Consumer<Long> getConsumer() {
                    return stringConsumer;
                }
            });
        };
    }

    class LocalRepository {
        static DataSetRepo dataSetRepo = new DataSetRepo();

        static void forEach(QueryExecutionContext executionContext) {
            executionContext.getConsumer().accept(dataSetRepo.queryResults(executionContext));
        }

    }

    interface QueryExecutionContext {

        String getQuery();

        Consumer<Long> getConsumer();
    }

    class DataSetRepo {
        List<String> cacheOf = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B");

        long queryResults(QueryExecutionContext context) {
            return cacheOf.stream().filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getQuery())).count();
        }
    }
```